# How do I launch a process to a specific monitor in Fluxbox?

Tags: xorg, multi-monitor, fluxbox

I have a four monitor setup. How do I launch a graphical process (ie, inkscape) to a specific monitor via terminal? IIRC it involves setting the DISPLAY variable. How do I also list what possible values that variable could contain?

OS is Debian 8. Window manager is Fluxbox.

Comment: What desktop environment or window manager are you using? (And by the way, no, it isn't `DISPLAY`: a value of `DISPLAY` designates the whole display, not a specific monitor.)

Comment: I'm using fluxbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many applications support a command line option `-geometry` or `--geometry` with a [geometry specification](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/man/man7/X.7.xhtml#heading7) as argument. The geometry can specify the window size, the position, or both. A position indirectly specifies the monitor, since all monitors are notionally organized on a plane. To see how your monitors are organized, run `xrandr`; an indication like “connected 1600x1200+1600+0” means that this monitor is 1600 pixels wide, 1200 tall, and its upper left corner is at position x=1600,y=0. So to launch xterm on this monitor (at the top left), I could use

```
xterm -geometry +1600+0
```

This does not work with inkscape, though: it doesn't support this option.

With inkscape, you can't easily force a specific instance to be at a specific position. But you can make your window manager place inkscape windows on a specific monitor, or at a specific position, if the window manager has this feature. Fluxbox does have this feature. It is configured through the [apps file](http://fluxbox.org/help/man-fluxbox-apps.php) `~/.fluxbox/apps`.

```
[app] (name=inkscape)
[Head] {1}
[end]
```

A “head” is a monitor in [X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) speak.

This may not work with some proprietary video drivers (last I looked, the Nvidia proprietary driver pretended that the display was a single rectangular screen instead of correctly reporting separate monitors). If `[Head]` doesn't work for you, you can use `[Position]` to force the window at a specific position.